# How to fetch and reset modules in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I got 2 modules
#module A

```
const state = {
    a: '',
    b: '',
    c: '',
}
const mutations = {
    reset(state) {
    state.a = ''
    state.b = ''
    state.c = ''
  }
}
```

I use vuex-map-fields to enable two-way-binding in componentA

After that I want to fetch all states of module A to module B (state.items), and RESET after done fetching
#module B

```
const state = {
 items: []
},
const mutations = {
    addItem (state) {
        state.items.push(moduleA.state)
    },
}
```

I tried

```
dispatch('moduleB/addItems')
commit('molduleA/reset')
```

with **data of moduleA**

```
const state = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: '3',
}
```

but it's not working, only store **reset state** of moduleA

#resultOfModuleB

```
const state = {
 items: [
    {a:'', b:'', c:''}
 ]
},
```

If I only dispatch(‘moduleB/addItems’), it's working

```
const state = {
 items: [
    {a:'1', b:'2', c:'3'}
 ]
},
```

What is the best way to do? Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "its working If I only dispatch(....)". Then state of module B contains the module A state and module A state is empty? Whats in A before you add it to B's items? I hope I can help you out if you could add some more info to your question.

Comment: @db3000 I edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I think I understand your problem now. Correct me if I'm wrong!
If you just call the ModuleB function, then B is containing the data of A.state as it should. But if you call the reset function on A.state both are empty.

The reason for this could be because of the way you add the A.state object to your B.state.
By pushing the A.state object into the B.state.items array you are not coping the object or its values. You just pass the address where the object is located in the memory.

So A.state and the element of the B.state.items array are "looking" at the same location in the memory. If you now rest A.state, therefore the B.state.items array element is also changed.

You can try to fix this with a deepCopy of the state array. There are functions like cloneDeep in lodash or similar to do so. But to understand fully what is going on you can write such a function your self because its not that hard.

```
function deepCopy(obj) {
  const retObj = {}
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => {
    retObj[prop] = obj[prop];
  });

  return retObj
}
```

This function should work with objects like yours and in your case. (If your objects have nested properties it wont work because of the way its accessing the properties)

I hope I didnt miss anything and could help you somehow!

Comment: I have solved this problem. As you said, that's because of *pass the address*.

My method: create a **getter** in moduleA and paste to moduleB, after that, I can freely reset moduleA without any problems

Comment: glad i could help!